# Marking a course as complete automatically if all sub modules are marked as complete rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

**Edit #1**

Here is what I have now

```
<% if course.complete? %>
  <%= link_to "Completed", course, class: "block text-lg w-full text-center text-white px-4 py-2 bg-green hover:bg-green-dark border-2 border-green-dark leading-none no-underline" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "View Modules", course, class: "block text-lg w-full text-center text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
<% end %>
```

course_module.rb

```
class CourseModule < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :course
  has_many :course_exercises

  validates :title, :course_id, presence: true

  scope :completed, -> { where(complete: true) }

  after_save :course_completed

  private

  def course_completed
    course = course_module.course
    course.update(complete: true) if course.course_modules.all?(&:complete?)
  end
end
```

The names match so no issues there, however, how would I go about calling the model method?

**Original Question**

Currently, I have courses and within the course I have modules both have complete columns which are a boolean, currently, students can complete modules by clicking on the tick like so

[image]

I have the courses database like so

[image: course]

and the modules table like so

[image: modules]

But I want the functionality to work so when the last module is marked as complete, the course itself gets marked as complete in the database, currently in the `course_modules_controller.rb` I have

```
def complete
  @course_module = CourseModule.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @course_module.complete = true
  @course_module.save
  redirect_to courses_path, notice: 'Module completed, congratulations!'
end
```

This works for the modules, but I want to mark the course as complete if the last task has been marked as complete.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in your controller or in an `after_save` in your model, but it'll look something like this:

```
course = course_module.course
course.update(complete: true) if course.course_modules.all?(&:complete?)
```

May require minor edits if the names don't quite match your schema.

Comment: It would be better to use a database query instead of `all?` but the direction is right.

Comment: See edit #1 of the original question, just to make sure I'm doing this correctly :)

Comment: @B.J.B you changed the question drastically with this "update"

Answer (score 1):

Seems this logic would belong in the `CourseModule` not the `Course` since the `CourseModule` being completed is the trigger.

Something akin to

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord 

  def complete!
    update_attribute(:complete,true) unless complete?
  end
end 

class CourseModule < ApplicationRecord
  scope :completed, -> {where(complete: true) }

  after_save :update_course, if: :complete?

  private
    def update_course
      course.complete! if course.course_modules.count == course.course_modules.completed.count
    end
end
```

If a `CourseModule` can become incomplete after being completed then you will have to change a bit of the logic here.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this question is a combination of both @elliotcm and @engineersmnky's answers.

The final answer is this:

course.rb

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :course_modules

  def complete!
    update_attribute(:complete, true)
  end
end
```

course_module.rb

```
class CourseModule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course

  scope :completed, -> { where(complete: true) }
  scope :course_completed, -> { where(complete: true) }

  after_save :update_course, if: :complete?

  private

  def update_course
    course.complete! if course.course_modules.all?(&:complete?)
  end
end
```

**Thank you both for your help in this!**

**Update**

Above solution will run the callback on every save of `course_module` after it is complete. And will update the `course.complete` every time (if all its course modules are complete) even if it was already marked complete. Avoid all that by modifying the callbacks a bit:

```
class CourseModule < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :update_course, if: -> { complete_changed? && complete? }

  private

  def update_course
    return if course.complete? || CourseModule.where(course_id: course_id, complete: false).exists?
    course.complete!
  end
end
```

**Note:** You also need to handle the case where a course_module get incompleted and so, its corresponding `course` also needs to be marked incomplete.

Comment: You have duplicate scopes with exact same criteria in model `CourseModule`.

Comment: @BJB please see my edit. Hope it improves the code without adding any bugs. #NotTested

Comment: @JagdeepSingh why would you not just post an answer?

Comment: Yeah here's something I didn't think about. The course and modules are being marked as completed for all users, is there a way to do this by the user id?

Comment: @B.J.B you offered no insight into Course -> User Relationships so we cannot assist with this without understanding that relationship as well

Comment: @engineersmnky https://gyazo.com/e9d28bed78599d34695e79e4c5e4a917 https://gyazo.com/c91de147481d1ad803f5a2c632bdc049 a course is able to has_many :users and a user has_many :courses

Comment: @B.J.B this should technically be a HABTM relationship in this case which will involve a join table. Also it means a `Course` can never be "complete" as completion is a state of the relationship not the `Course` itself. You will need to rethink your design a bit to make this work appropriately

Comment: @engineersmnky So only the modules can be complete? Would it be worth creating a new question here to go about joining the table? Because I've never dealt with a HABTM relationship before.

Comment: *So only the modules can be complete?* No nothing can be "complete". *Would it be worth creating a new question here to go about joining the table?* Yes as this strays completely from the current question and to be honest the answers provided here will not really help you where you are going.